# How to compile source files with different-2 flags in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I am migrating my `make` build system to `cmake` so I need to compile the source files with different (2) flags and then create the static library.

For example I have:

```
$(OBJSGEN): $(OBJDIR1)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp 

$(CC) $(FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(DFLAGS) $(EFLAGS1) $(INCLUDES) -c $<  -o $@
```

Can any one please help me out?

Comment: What "different-2 flags" means? From you Makefile I see that you compile all sources with the **same flags**.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CMake's [object libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) to do this:

```
# compiles source.cpp with -DSOME_DEF=1
add_library(obj1 OBJECT source.cpp)

# This is the "modern" syntax for setting preprocessor definitions:
target_compile_definitions(obj1 PRIVATE SOME_DEF=1)

# compiles source.cpp with -DSOME_DEF=2
add_library(obj2 OBJECT source.cpp)

# This is the "old" way of setting preprocessor definitions:
set_target_properties(obj2 PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS SOME_DEF=2)

# creates a static library with both objects
add_library(lib STATIC
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:obj1>
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:obj2>)
```

**Edit:** I included CMake 2.8 compatible way of setting preprocessor definitions *per target* using [`set_target_properties`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.0/cmake.html#command:set_target_properties).

Comment: I am wondering to see the error in command
"target_compile_definitions"
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:243 (target_compile_definitions):
  Unknown CMake command "target_compile_definitions".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Comment: Strange. What version of CMake do you use?

Comment: Tried with 
cmake version 2.8.8, Ubuntu 14.04 and 
cmake version 3.5.1, Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Right, `target_compile_definitions` is not supported by 2.8, but 3.5 should work... Anyway, the command adds preprocessor definitions. Instead, you could use `add_definitions`, which is the old thing of doing this. 

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.0/cmake.html#command:add_definitions

Comment: Yes I used add_definitions command....
thanks a lot man.. I appreciate you.

Comment: With diff-2 flags means: I want to compile my source files with some flags but I do not need all flags for all files.
For better understanding have a look at my code below:
add_definitions(${FLAGS} ${CFLAGS} ${DFLAGS} ${EFLAGS1})
add_library(OBJ1 OBJECT ${SRC_DIR1})
remove_definitions(${EFLAGS1})
add_definitions(${EFLAGS2})
add_library(OBJ2 OBJECT ${SRC_DIR2})
add_library(${TARGET_LIB_STATIC} STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:OBJ1> $<TARGET_OBJECTS:OBJ2>)
All source files are getting compiled with all flags while I have added remove_definitions command to remove one flag.

Comment: My requirement is: 
EFLAGS1 should remove and set EFLAGS2 before compiling OBJ2.

Please help me. I explored a lot on cmake but could not find any solution.

Comment: I've updated the example to show both new and old syntax. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have upgraded cmake to 3.2.2 and target_compile_definitions command is perfectly working on it... Thank you for your fast response.

Is there any way to collect all object files (.o) into a particular directory?